# Can Firebase's GeoFire be downloaded via Swift Package Manager?

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods, swift-package-manager, geofire

Can Firebase's GeoFire be downloaded via Swift Package Manager?

I read a comment [here](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/157) that it can be if Firebase is installed under the main branch instead of a version rule, but the Firebase docs only mention installing via CocoaPods.

Also, if it is possible this way, isn't it still recommended that Firebase is installed under a version rule and not the main branch?

My main concern is that I have Firebase fully integrated in my project via SPM, but now I want to add the GeoFire product. If GeoFire must be installed with CocoaPods, do I have to completely uninstall Firebase from SPM and reinstall it as a cocoa pod, or can I leave it with both...

Comment: I would be very keen to know as well. I can try run packages using Cocoa Pods and Swift Package Manager, but this is a bit more work. I would rather stay with Swift Package Manager if possible.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I don't think it is unfortunately :(

Comment: Exactly! GeoFire with CocoaPods and Firebase with SPM they don't work together. I'm trying to extract GeoFire library and add it manually and use Objective-C bridging header. I don't know if it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it worked for me:

1. I downloaded GeoFire/Objective-C from github
   https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc
2. Unzipped the library and copied the contents of the API, Implementation and Utils
   folders into corresponding folders I created in my SwiftUI project. The result
   was something like this:
   GeoFireObjcFiles
   API
   h GeoFire
   h GFCircleQuery
   h GFQuery
   h GFRegionQuery
   Implementation
   h GFQuery+Private
   m GFQuery
   h GeoFire+Private
   m GeoFire
   Utils
   h GFBase32Utils
   m GFBase32Utils
   h GFGeoHash
   m GFUtils
   h GFUtils
   m GFGeoQueryBounds
   h GFGeoQueryBounds
   m GfGeoHashQuery
   h GFGeoHashQuery
   m GFGeoHash
3. I created a Bridging Header and #import'ed all the objective-C .h files into it
   See [CallObjectiveCFromSwift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-do-i-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)
4. I made sure the .m files are added to BuildPhases->CompileSources list

And that was it. I built and everything was fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on exactly how you did this? I'm trying to follow your answer and I'm not getting the same result.